# ¿Como publico mi aplicativo web con ionic 2 en mi servidor pago de godaddy?

Tags: ionic2, godaddy

Realice un proyecto utilizando el marco de `ionic` 2 y quiero subir los archivos del aplicativo web a mi servicio de `hosting` en `GoDaddy` pero no se exactamente que archivos debo publicar para que mi aplicativo web funcione en mi dominio, Alguien me podría dar una idea de como hacer esto? el  arbol de mi proyecto es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Resolviste tu problema?

tienes que subir los archivos comprimidos mediante cpanel, posteriormente descomprimirlos y configurar la ruta del index principal para que la redirija a public_html en lugar de www, espero haber sido de ayuda, saludos.